# Cannot use VB because another language has been specified

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error on a page that has been working fine until recently. I was wondering if someone can help me identify the cause of this error as I have tried everything I can to fix it, with no success.

**Error Message:**

> Error 27  Cannot use 'VB' because another language has been specified
>   earlier in this page (or was implied from a CodeFile
>   attribute).   W:\admin.fctl.ucf.edu\inventory\old\address.ascx    2

**My code:**

```
<%@ Control CodeBehind="address.ascx.cs" Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Inventory1.address" %>
<Script language="VB" runat="Server">

        Public Property Address1 as string
            Get
                Return txtAddress1.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtAddress1.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property Address2 as string
            Get
                Return txtAddress2.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtAddress2.text = value
            End Set 
        End property

        Public Property city as string
            Get
                Return txtcity.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtcity.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property state as string
            Get
                Return cbostate.selecteditem.text
            End Get
            Set
                cbostate.selectedindex = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property zip as string
            Get
                Return txtzip.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtzip.text = value
            End Set 
        End property

        Public Property country as string
            Get
                Return cbocountry.selecteditem.text
            End Get
            Set
                cbocountry.selectedindex = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property phone1 as string
            Get
                Return txtphone1.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtphone1.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property phone2 as string
            Get
                Return txtphone2.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtphone2.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property mobile as string
            Get
                Return txtmobile.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtmobile.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property email as string
            Get
                Return txtemail.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtemail.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property fax as string
            Get
                Return txtfax.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtfax.text = value
            End Set     
        End property

        Public Property pager as string
            Get
                Return txtpager.text
            End Get
            Set
                txtpager.text = value
            End Set     
        End property
</Script>
```

Comment: `<%@ Control CodeBehind="address.ascx.cs" Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Inventory1.address" %>
<Script language="VB" runat="Server">` <-- Could your problem lie in these two lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code behind is in C#:

```
<%@ Control CodeBehind="address.ascx.cs" Language="c#"
```

Because of that, you can only embed C# code into the page, not VB code.  Either use entirely VB for both the code behind and the embedded scriptlets, or use entirely C# in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link to convert the vb.net to C# and then you don't have to worry about it

[VB to C# Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

OR:

Why don't you just compile your VB code into a library(.dll).Reference it later from your code and that's it. Managed dlls contain MSIL to which both c# and vb are compiled

Comment: I assume you mean C#, not C.  Having C code would not be useful at all here.

Comment: Yet in your post you say C, not C#.  You should fix that.  Also, clarifying questions don't belong in answers, they belong as comments.

Comment: To your second point, that's not strictly possible here.  The idea is that the single markup/codebehind file is compiled into a single *class*, and a single class can't be defined in multiple languages.  You can't define part of a class in an external library, particularly given that each section references the other.  There really is no way around converting one or the other so that they are both in the same language.